# How to create an Oracle database inside Vagrant and connect to it in my local Rails app and SQL Developer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, oracle, vagrant, oracle-sqldeveloper

I followed instructions at https://github.com/oracle/vagrant-boxes's `OracleDatabase/18.3.0/README.md`.

When the `vagrant up` installation finished, it outputs in terminal:

```
oracle-18c-vagrant: ORACLE PASSWORD FOR SYS, SYSTEM AND PDBADMIN: my_password
```

I tried to connect to this database via SQL Developer with the following values in the new database connection window:

- Connection Name: `my_local_oracle_db`
- Username: `PDBADMIN`
- Password: `my_password`
- Connection Type: `Basic`
- Hostname: `localhost`
- Port: `1521`
- SID: `ORCLCDB`

But it gives me an error: `ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`

Q1) Do I need to create a new database inside vagrant first? What instruction can I use to create it?

Q2) And what value should I enter to connect to it using SQL Developer?

Next, to connect it using Rails

I used this config in `config/database.yml`:

```
test:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  hostname: localhost
  port: 1521
  username: PDBADMIN
  password: my_password
```

But when I did `rails db:migrate`, it failed with this error:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=test rails db:migrate
Warning: NLS_LANG is not set. fallback to US7ASCII.
rails aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass
```

Q3) What values should I be entering into config/database.yml?

My Rails app has `ruby-oci8` and `activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter` gems installed.

Comment: PDBADMIN is the account to connect to pluggable database ORCLPDB1. ORCLPDB1 is the SERVICE_NAME. ORCLCDB is the instance (process + memory = SID). Always use SERVICE_NAME when connecting to the database. Use lsnrctl status to see what services are exposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q1) Do I need to create a new database inside vagrant first? What instruction can I use to create it?**

I think the database is already created inside vagrant so I don't need to create it again.

**Q2) And what value should I enter to connect to it using SQL Developer?**

Enter the following values in the new database connection window:

```
Connection Name: my_local_oracle_db
Username: SYS
Password: my_password
Role: SYSDBA
Connection Type: Basic
Hostname: localhost
Port: 1521
SID: ORCLCDB
```

This will connect me to the SYS user in the database.

but I think for what I want, I need to create another user in the same database using the SYS user.

To do this, after connecting to the above database in SQL Developer, run below SQL commands:

```
CREATE USER C##db_name_here IDENTIFIED BY my_password2 DEFAULT TABLESPACE "USERS" TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP" ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
GRANT CONNECT TO C##db_name_here;
GRANT RESOURCE TO C##db_name_here;
GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO C##db_name_here;
GRANT CREATE VIEW TO C##db_name_here;
GRANT CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TO C##db_name_here;
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO C##db_name_here;
GRANT CREATE TYPE TO C##db_name_here;
GRANT CREATE DATABASE LINK TO C##db_name_here;
```

This user will be the one I connect to in my Rails `config/database.yml`

**Q3) What values should I be entering into config/database.yml?**

```
test:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  hostname: localhost
  port: 1521
  database: ORCLCDB
  username: C##db_name_here
  password: my_password2
```

Answer (score 1):

Q1: No you don't have to create a database; the Vagrantfile creates a CDB (ORCLCDB) and a PDB (ORCLPDB1).
When the provisioning completes both are ready to use.

See [About the Multitenant Architecture](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/multi/introduction-to-the-multitenant-architecture.html#GUID-C5B0AF7D-ABE8-4F69-9552-F4DAF40281F1) if you are unfamiliar with the Multitenant concept.

Q2: As already mentioned by Bjarte, to connect to the PDB you need to use the `Service Name` option instead of the `SID`.
The `PDBADMIN` user only exists in the `ORCLPDB1` PDB, so you need to specify `ORCLPDB1` as service.

Note that `PDBADMIN` does not have a lot of privileges after install, you probably want to first connect to the CDB as `SYSTEM` and grant more privileges to `PDBADMIN` -- E.g.

```
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=ORCLPDB1
GRANT DBA TO PDBADMIN
```

Also note that you have a typo in the port number (1512 instead of 1521)

Q3: See the [oracle-enhanced documentation](https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/tree/master#database-connection)

The following works for me:

```
development:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  database: //localhost:1521/orclpdb1
  username: pdbadmin
  password: MySecretPassword
```

```
$ rake db:migrate
== 20200319203904 CreateAuthors: migrating ====================================
-- create_table(:authors)
   -> 0.0628s
== 20200319203904 CreateAuthors: migrated (0.0630s) ===========================
```

Comment: Thank you for giving the helpful information. But when I run `ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=ORCLPDB1` and `GRANT DBA TO PDBADMIN`, I got an error saying `ORA-00922: missing or invalid option`. But I have a found solution for my problem now and I have post it below, so I will just be upvoting your post and select my answer as the selected answer. Thank you for spending time helping me solve this problem.

Comment: Right. With this Vagrant box you can either use the CDB or the PDB, whatever you prefer.